# Why doesn't Go chaincode need annotations?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

By looking at chaincode-java and chaincode-go in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic, I find the java implementation requires annotations like `@Transaction` and `@Contract`, while the Go one does not.

As in Java, I can use `@Contract(name)` to change contract name, how would I do so in Go?

If Go doesn't need `@Transaction(intent)`, why does Java require it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go does not support annotations. `fabric-contract-api-go` turns into an accessible operation every public method that has a smart contract as receiver and uses reflection to build metadata and such kind of things (from v2.X).

Java supports annotations. Reflection in Java works in a different way than in Go and its performance is really poor. Thus, annotations are preferred.

Languages differ from each other in many things apart from its syntax.

And about chaincode name, you specify your preferred name and version number when packaging your Go chaincode. It does not depend on the source code.

Comment: One chaincode may contain multiple contracts. Could you give more info on how to alter contract names? Also Java differentiates intent=submit vs intent=evaluate. Why doesn't it matter in Go?

Comment: To answer my own question, the intent in Transaction is informational. For Go, all transactions are being marked as `submit` as revealed by `org.hyperledger.fabric:GetMetadata`.

Comment: `ContractInterface` defines the method `GetName()` to return your contract name. And yes, intent is informational: An evaluation is needed for the endorsement of any transaction and your client can transact a query that does not alter the state if it wants to.